# How to search Sublime Text changelog?

Tags: sublime-text

I opened the Sublime Text changelog (Help / Changelog). How do I search it now?

I think it's bizarre Sublime Text opens the changelog in a new window, rather than the text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem possible. Alternatively, you can view (and search) the changelog on their site:

- Sublime Text 2: https://www.sublimetext.com/2
- Sublime Text 3: https://www.sublimetext.com/3

Answer (score 1):

There actually *is* a way to search/view the changelog locally. In your Sublime Text installation folder, there is a file named `changelog.txt`. In ST2, and ST3 builds up to 3065, this is just a plain text file. However, if you're using the latest ST3 public beta (Build 3083), or the ST3 [dev builds](http://sublimetext.com/3dev) (you must be a registered user to use them), the file is actually in HTML format. Rename it to `changelog.html` and open it in your web browser to view.